# convert a java project (I used in it JLayer 1.0.1 to play mp3) to a runnable jar file

Tags: java, swing, audio, jlayer

I built a java project and I used (JLayer 1.0.1) to play mp3 audio.
when I test my project with eclipce I find that it worked correctly 100% and the JLayer 1.0.1 libraries play my mp3 files efficiently.
but when I convert it into a runnable jar file it works with **NO SOUND OR AUDIO**.
It seems that my program can't reach for Jlayer 1.0.1 libraries.
So now,I need your help to resolve this problem.
*with my thanks*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following in order to test your application: export your project as a regular jar and copy it together with the JLayer.jar and other dependencies to a directory. Then, create a batch file (.bat on Windows, .sh on Linux) that would include something like this:

```
java -cp yourjar.jar;JLayer.jar;other_jars FullPathToYourClass
```

where `FullPathToYourClass` is something like `com.something.else.ClassName`
Also note the the separator on Linux is :

Once you see it working, you can start to do a build script to do the above automatically. I would suggest you build an Ant build.xml file for this.

Answer (score 3):

This can be a JRE issue (Eclipse can be using a different JRE from what your system uses), or a packaging problem.

When packaging using Eclipse, make sure you package all libs together with your classes. Do to that, select the option "Extract required libraries into generated JAR".

Another option is to run your JAR setting the classpath: `java -cp yourjar.jar;yourlib1.jar;yourlib2.jar com.your.package.YourMainClass` (note that the ';' is platform dependent) instead of `java -jar yourjar.jar`.